# Calculator for multiplying price and quantity

Tags: c++, beginner, calculator

I'm coding with c++. Basically the question is about to make calculation of any product and calculate with price and quantity with our name. Anyone can simplify this coding?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string star = "*****************************************************************************************";
    string name;
    string productName1, productName2;
    int quantity1, quantity2;
    float price1, price2;
    float afterPrice1, afterPrice2;
    float totalPrice;
    cout<< "Please enter your name: ";
    getline(cin,name);
    cout<< endl;
    cout<< "\t Please enter information for first order :" << endl;
    cout<< "\t Product name : ";
    getline(cin,productName1);
    cout<< "\t Quantity : ";
    cin>> quantity1;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<< "\t Price : RM";
    cin>> price1;
    cout<< endl << endl;
    cout<< "\t Product name : ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,productName2);
    cout<<"\t quantity : ";
    cin>> quantity2;
    cout<< endl;
    cout<< "\t Price : RM";
    cin>> price2;
    cout<< endl << endl;
    cout<< star << endl;
    cout<< "\t name : " << name << endl;
    cout<< star << endl;
    cout<< "\t Order Info: " << endl;
    afterPrice1= quantity1*price1;
    cout<< "\t Product 1:" << productName1 << endl;
    cout<< "\t Price : RM" << afterPrice1 <<endl;
    afterPrice2=quantity2*price2;
    cout<< "\t Product 2: " << productName2 << endl;
    cout<< "\t Price: RM" << afterPrice2<< endl;
    totalPrice=afterPrice1+afterPrice2;
    cout << "\t Total Price: RM" << totalPrice;
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## General Observations

The variable names are generally very meaningful.

There is no error checking on user input.

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

## Prefer `"\n"` Over `std::endl`

For performance reasons you should use `std::cout << "\n";` to terminate output lines rather than `std::cout << std::endl;`. `std::endl` flushes the output buffer which is generally not necessary. Flushing the output buffer means that the code is calling a system function and this call cause program delays in a time sharing environment.

## Use Data Structures Such as `struct` or `class` to Represent Complex Data

The line items the program is collecting the data for should be a data structure, this would make breaking the program into smaller easier to program pieces easier.

```
class product {
public:
    product() 
        : price{0}, quantity{0}
    {}
    std::string productName;
    float price;
    int quantity;
};
```

This would also allow you to create arrays or vectors of the product so that the program isn't limited to 2 items in the list.

## Function Complexity

It would be better to break the code up into functions that perform single operations, such as `getUserInput` and `printOutput`. As programs grow in size the use of `main()` should be limited to calling functions that parse the command line, calling functions that set up for processing, calling functions that execute the desired function of the program, and calling functions to clean up after the main portion of the program.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.